# How to use ember.js with google app engine template

Tags: google-app-engine, ember.js

If you know it,please tell me it.

I think that both ember.js and GAE tempate use similar syntax so they conflicts,as following.

```
{{ view }}
```

What shoud I do to resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide more concrete example but ill take a wild guess: you are putting it on a jsp? Dont. Put it on a html file instead.

Comment: Just quick to tell you note that I use GAE for python.I'll prepare with more concrete example.

Comment: Same thing. Serve it on a html page not a python template

Comment: If you know it,please tell me it,serving static html page.